# Is it possible to scale pharo user interface on hidpi display?

Tags: pharo

I'm trying to use pharo 4.0 on 4k laptop. Is it possible to scale gui interface (not just fonts)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to solve this problem. If you have multiple displays, you can use a display which is dedicated for Pharo.

1. Use the native resolution. For instance. 3840x2160.
2. Go to World -> System -> Settings and change font size to 24, and click update then apply. Click Store Settings in the end.
   [image]

**How does it look like.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022 and there's still no solution for HiDPI. But I just found out a "solution", at least for the editor:

1. go to Pharo > Settings > Appearance
2. set `Display scale factor` to `0.5`
3. tweak standard font sizes

This is not a definitive solution because some widgets don't respect this setting (for example the top menu and the tab buttons on the Browser).